# How to monitor IIS application pool worker process using PRTG Network Monitor

Tags: iis, iis-8, application-pool, iis-8.5, prtg

I have an asp.net mvc application deployed in IIS. Sometimes its application pool worker process hangs so using PRTG Network Monitor I have added a sensor: Application Pool PerfCounter IIS. How can I configure it in order to when application pool worker process hangs I can see it in the graph?

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Powershell* module `WebAdministration` to get pool details

```powershell
# import module
Import-Module WebAdministration

# get your pool worker process
$process=$(dir IIS:\AppPools\Wikifolio.Web.API\WorkerProcesses)
# show everything for this process
Get-Process -Id $process.processId | Select *
```

This will give you large amount of data about this process

I am usually interested in following parameters: `PrivateMemorySize64`,`WorkingSet64`,`StartTime`,`Id`,`Threads`,`HandleCount`,`CPU`

In our case whenever `HandleCount` is over 10 thousand i need to raise alarm or if CPU goes over specific amount of % then it is time to act